# How do I make the command texdoc latex2e to open the PDF version by default?

Tags: pdf, miktex, documentation, viewers, texdoc

I found a `latex2e.pdf` in my MiKTeX installation tree. How do I make `texdoc latex2e` open the PDF version by default?

**UPDATE**:
I tried renaming `latex2e.html` to something else, and now the PDF version is opened by default. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The ordered list of extensions used by `mthelp` (the real program behind the name `texdoc` on MiKTeX) can be set in the registry.

In the registry editor, create the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MiKTeX.org\MiKTeX\2.8\mthelp` if it doesn't exist yet, then add a new string value named `DocExtensions` and set the associated data to, eg `.chm;.pdf;.html;.dvi;.ps;.txt` (that is, the default value with pdf move forward). Obviously, you need to replace `2.8` with your actual MiKTeX version number.

Also, you may replace `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` if you want the change to affect all users (and have sufficient privileges).

Comment: There is now a more comprehensive answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54490/9237.